# Converting RowStyle values Conditionally

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

So I don't know if this is really possible, but it is worth a shot. I have two different `DatagridRowStyles` that I want to set in the `DataGridBaseStyle` Conditionally.

For example:

```
      <Style x:Key="DataGridBaseStyle"
                   TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
                <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellBaseStyle}" />
                <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderBaseStyle}" />
                <Setter Property="RowHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowHeaderBaseStyle}" />
                <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowBaseStyle} />
...
```

The property setter value of RowStyle I want to use one of two Styles depending on what "Custom Theme" I am using.

So far I tried setting it this way, but it only defaults to the normal style.

```
<Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <conv:DataGridRowStyleConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

And the same with

```
<Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowBaseStyle} Converter={StaticResource DataGridRowStyleConverter}" />
```

Converter Coding

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (ColourScheme == "Dark")
            return Application.Current.Resources["DataGridRowBaseDarkStyle"] as Style;

        return Application.Current.Resources["DataGridRowBaseStyle"] as Style;
    }
```

I am kind of thinking that my converter return values are incorrect, but I also did play around with those values with no luck.

Comment: I think, your convert method code is incorrect. You should check the value parameter of the Convert() method by typecasting it to DataGridRowBaseStyle instead of ColourScheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `ColorScheme` is a public property in the current DataContext, the Setter should look like this:

```
<Setter Property="RowStyle"
    Value="{Binding ColorScheme, Converter={StaticResource DataGridRowStyleConverter}}"/>
```

or like this in XML tag syntax:

```
<Setter Property="RowStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Path="ColorScheme"
                 Converter="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyleConverter}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The Converter would get the current value of the ColorScheme by the `value` argument of the Convert method:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value.ToString == "Dark"
        ? Application.Current.Resources["DataGridRowBaseDarkStyle"] as Style
        : Application.Current.Resources["DataGridRowBaseStyle"] as Style;
}
```

Comment: No the ColorScheme Property is not public. But I see what you did there, the only thing is that the issue is Setting the Property Value to the right style. Even if I return the correct style it then uses the base default style of silverlight.@Clemens